# NSMutableArray release objects inserted. -> cause memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Hi I have a lot of problems to remove the objects of my mutable array.

I have a method which send back a mutable initialized with a custom object.
This mutable is declared like autorelease for releasing after method.
In my return, I retain the mutable to not loose it.
I want in this second method to remove the content of my mutable and release my mutable.
But my app quit and fail.

```
  //first method which return my mutable

 NSMutableArray *highScores = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease] ;

    for (....)
    {

    HighScore *currentHighScore = [[HighScore alloc] init];

    currentHighScore.user = name;
    currentHighScore.score = score;

     //add to the array
    [highScores addObject:currentHighScore];
    [currentHighScore release];

    }

return highScores;

// method which use the first method

//retrieve with retain to keep.

    highScoreList = [[HighScoreViewController getHighScores:NormalGameModeXML]retain] ; 

    HighScore *currentHighScore;

    int count = [highScoreList count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
    {
        currentHighScore = [highScoreList objectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

This is working, but off course I have memory leak for all the objects in the mutable not released.
But if i'm trying to release the object of the mutable and the mutable itself by this :

```
//remove Mutable array content.
//[highScoreList removeAllObjects] ;
//[highScoreList release];
```

My app is quitting.

Do you have a solution to avoid the memory leak and clean it well?

Comment: if you run in debug when your app crashes, what does it say on the console? what is on the stack trace?

Comment: Where exactly do you see this memory leak? That the program crashes in the 2dn case is obvious. You're releasing a autorelease object.

Comment: Filip : when i'm running in debug for scenario 2 (release and remove objects) : EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Nils: without the scenario 2, we have a memory leak because we retain it in last method and never release it. ( [[HighScoreViewController getHighScores:NormalGameModeXML]retain] )

Comment: @nils what autoreleased object are you talking about? I can't see him releasing anything that hasn't been properly retained, unless he's trying to use `currentHighScore` later on after he released the `highScoreList`, but that's never mentioned.

Comment: @Tommy EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you're trying to access an object that has been dealloc'd already. Are you trying to use the `currentHighScore` object after you release the `highScoreList`? I think that would probably crash (depending on what NSArray does in the `objectAtIndex:` method, but I think it would crash).

Comment: @Tommy: you're right, didn't scroll so far right ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using NSZombieEnabled to check the reason for an EXC_BAD_ACCESS..

[HowTo is found here..](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Thx a lot, the problem was the dealloc of my highscore (username) was released and never instantiated.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    //[highScoreList removeAllObjects] ;
    //[highScoreList release];
```

No need to `removeAllObjects` prior to release.

Note that if you use `highScoreList` after it is deallocated, your app will crash as you describe.  I.e. if you use `highScoreList` after the above, *BOOM*.

You could set `highScoreList` to `nil`, but a better solution is to understand why you are using an object after you think you should be done with it.

And, as always:

## If there is a crash, there is a backtrace.  Post it.